# Quickly removing a list of elements from lists in the column of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I have a dataframe with a column of the form of fruit

```
data = {
    'fruit': [['apple', 'banana', 'cherry'], ['banana', 'orange'], None, [], ['cherry', 'grape'], ['apple']],
    'location': ['New York', 'Los Angeles', 'Chicago', 'Miami', 'San Francisco', 'Seattle']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to remove the elements of the list

```
gone_off_fruit=['banana','cherry']
```

currently, i am using this

```
def remove_gone_off_fruit(fruit_list):
    if fruit_list:
        return [fruit for fruit in fruit_list if fruit not in gone_off_fruit]
    else:
        return tag_list

df['fruit'] = df['fruit'].apply(remove_gone_off_fruit)
```

but it is very slow, what's the fastest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you want to check if `fruit` is in `gone_off_fruit` in your list comprehension, you are looping through the entire `gone_off_fruit` list.

Hence, the running time for your `remove_gone_off_fruit` function is O(nm), where n is the number of fruits in `fruit_list`, and m is the number of fruits in `gone_off_fruit`.

You can improve your running time by switching to a data structure for which checking for the existence of an element in the structure takes constant time. A `set`, for example, would be a good option.

So, for example, change

```py
gone_off_fruit=['banana','cherry']
```

to

```py
gone_off_fruit=set(['banana','cherry'])
```

Answer (score 0):

This *listcomp* should be faster than the one invoked by your [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) :

```
df["fruit"] = [
    [fruit for fruit in lst if fruit not in gone_off_fruit]
    if lst else lst for lst in df["fruit"]
]
```

Output :

```
print(df)

      fruit       location
0   [apple]       New York
1  [orange]    Los Angeles
2      None        Chicago
3        []          Miami
4   [grape]  San Francisco
5   [apple]        Seattle
```